# Implement user specific chrome notification

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, notifications

I had a requirement in which I need to implement the chrome push notification but user specific. For example in case of facebook if a user receive any message a notification is send to him on the chrome. 
I know there are multiple vendors to broadcast the push notification like izooto.com, pushcrew.com etc. But they send the notification to all of the subscribed user.
What I want is to send the notification to an specific user. How can it be done.

Thanks

Comment: How do you plan to ensure that the specific user is available?

Comment: We do have a service as in like the facebook messages. So need to implement the notification for that specific user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible! izooto.com also has APIs for sending browser notifications to a specific user.

You can assign a unique ID to your subscriber called as 'Subscriber ID'. You can then use the 'Push to Subscriber ID' API to push notification to one or more such subscribers.

You can also assign a tag to your subscribers. A tag represents a specific segment in which user can fall for example you may add a tag "searched_a_product" which defines all the users who searched a product on to your site. Sending notifications to this tag will send notifications to all your subscribers who searched a product on your site.  And of course you can also push to all of your subscribers using the 'Push to all' API.

More details are in the [API documentation](http://apidocs.izooto.com/?javascript) and you can always get in touch with izooto support.